# floating panel as percentage of parent with parent height as percentage of body

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS setting:

[image]

My modal is a percentage of the body:

```
p-dialog.inViewer .ui-dialog {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

in the modal there is a floating div with the height that changes according the contents. The contents is scrollable so I am trying to set the height of the floating div so it is always contained in the modal.

So far I have the following CSS for the floating div:

```
p-dialog.inViewer p-tree.parts .ui-widget-content {
    border-style: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)!important;
    max-height: 44vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

but this is only working for big screen. I understand the problem is that I am defining the max-height based on a paren with height expressed as percentage. Do you know how can I achieve the desired layout? I need to have the modal centred in the screen and 95% of windows height and width.

Thank you for your help, Dino.

Comment: share code in a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.modal {
    width: calc(90vw - 80px);
    height: calc(90vh - 80px);
    overflow: hidden !important;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5vh;
}
.floating {
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: none;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    min-height: calc(90vh - 120px);
    max-height: calc(90vh - 120px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="floating">
    <p>Hoc inmaturo interitu ipse quoque sui pertaesus excessit e vita aetatis nono anno atque vicensimo cum quadriennio imperasset. natus apud Tuscos in Massa Veternensi, patre Constantio Constantini fratre imperatoris, matreque Galla sorore Rufini et Cerealis, quos trabeae consulares nobilitarunt et praefecturae.</p>
    <p>Verum ad istam omnem orationem brevis est defensio. Nam quoad aetas M. Caeli dare potuit isti suspicioni locum, fuit primum ipsius pudore, deinde etiam patris diligentia disciplinaque munita. Qui ut huic virilem togam deditšnihil dicam hoc loco de me; tantum sit, quantum vos existimatis; hoc dicam, hunc a patre continuo ad me esse deductum; nemo hunc M. Caelium in illo aetatis flore vidit nisi aut cum patre aut mecum aut in M. Crassi castissima domo, cum artibus honestissimis erudiretur.</p>
    <p>Novo denique perniciosoque exemplo idem Gallus ausus est inire flagitium grave, quod Romae cum ultimo dedecore temptasse aliquando dicitur Gallienus, et adhibitis paucis clam ferro succinctis vesperi per tabernas palabatur et conpita quaeritando Graeco sermone, cuius erat inpendio gnarus, quid de Caesare quisque sentiret. et haec confidenter agebat in urbe ubi pernoctantium luminum claritudo dierum solet imitari fulgorem. postremo agnitus saepe iamque, si prodisset, conspicuum se fore contemplans, non nisi luce palam egrediens ad agenda quae putabat seria cernebatur. et haec quidem medullitus multis gementibus agebantur.</p>
    <p>Pandente itaque viam fatorum sorte tristissima, qua praestitutum erat eum vita et imperio spoliari, itineribus interiectis permutatione iumentorum emensis venit Petobionem oppidum Noricorum, ubi reseratae sunt insidiarum latebrae omnes, et Barbatio repente apparuit comes, qui sub eo domesticis praefuit, cum Apodemio agente in rebus milites ducens, quos beneficiis suis oppigneratos elegerat imperator certus nec praemiis nec miseratione ulla posse deflecti.</p>
    <p>Et quia Montius inter dilancinantium manus spiritum efflaturus Epigonum et Eusebium nec professionem nec dignitatem ostendens aliquotiens increpabat, qui sint hi magna quaerebatur industria, et nequid intepesceret, Epigonus e Lycia philosophus ducitur et Eusebius ab Emissa Pittacas cognomento, concitatus orator, cum quaestor non hos sed tribunos fabricarum insimulasset promittentes armorum si novas res agitari conperissent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tweaked the code a bit to accomodate a scrolling area inside my floating div. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem ! Glad I could help.